# Forcing a user to use a specific Citrix Server

Tags: citrix

Is there any way to force a particular Login or AD group to use a specific Citrix Server in a Citrix Farm? We have a Citrix server that is having issue and we would like certain high use accounts to use only the server that is acting appropriately until we can get the second server fixed. I have not really found anything helpful on the web about this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are publishing applications to these users, correct?
The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to create duplicate applications, point the new apps to the specific server only and then add the user id's to an ad group or directly to the published app.

The end result is unless you remove the users from the old published app they may see two icons.

Comment: this worked like a charm, now just to convince the support company they have an faulty server that they need to rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to take the suspect server off of the farm until it is working properly.

Comment: hehe..thats not gonna happen unfortunately, we have been dealing with this for several months now, Im just the on the support team for this program not even responsible for this other than taking calls about sessions locking up...